# Find the shortest distance along the outer surface of a pyramid

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider a pyramid with square base PQSR and vertex O.  Given that all the edges are of equal length of 20m, find the shortest distance from P to the midpoint of OR along the outer surface of the pyramid.

Just to clarify the base of the pyramid is such that P is opposite R diagonally.

Any tips?

I've calculated multiple sensible routes which do not give the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider the unfolded surface of the pyramid on the plane.

[image]

(credits: http://holgerweb.net/PhD/WWWMasters/other/texture_mapping.htm)

then by law of cosine

$$d^2=20^2+10^2-2\cdot 20\cdot 10 \cos (120)=700 \implies d=10 \sqrt 7$$

Comment: I had already considered this, but didn't get far.  It appears that the path may be from P to the midpoint of SR and then to the midpoint of OR?  but this is not the correct answer?

Comment: @darren86 We need to consider different paths and yhe choose the optimal one.

Comment: I've tried many paths before posting this but my solution is not correct according to the answer book.  May I ask what solution you get, to check the answer book is correct?

Comment: The correct answer will be a straight line with no turning points when the pyramid is unfolded in the plane. The tricky part is to make sure you don't cut the pyramid along the shortest path while you're unfolding it. In this case, there are two shortest paths, so you can afford to cut one but must not cut both.

Comment: @darren86 The solution should be the length of the base of a triangle with sides 20 and 10 and an angle between equal to 120 degree. We can use law of cosine to determine it.

Comment: @gimusi your solution is correct.  It has taken me a while to visualise this but I think I've finally got it.  Thank you.

Comment: @darren86 Well done! Sorry but Itesterdey I gave the solution from the mobile and I can't make a more clear sketch about the derivation. I'm happy that you finally figured out that. You are welcome, Bye.

Answer (score 3):

Unfold the pyramid and use the pythagoras theorem:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is helping me visualise the problem better.  You introduce a new triangle MNP, how is ON 10m?

Comment: @darren86, we know that the $M$ is the midpoint of $OR$ and this is also true for point $N$ if we imagine another triangle like $POK$ which vertex $K$ is at the opposite of point $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as others but perhaps worth considering:

We know we need to move across two faces to get from start to finish. The optimal point for crossing the border of the two faces minimizes the sum of the lengths across each face.

The apex angles near P are congruent, 60 degrees. The length of the edges is known,l.

Let $x$ be the distance from P along the boundary edge.

Then the distance travelled by the cosine rule is

$$L=\sqrt{d^2/4+x^2-dx/2}+\sqrt{x^2+d^2-xd}$$

Now you can minimize in the usual way by differentiating.

Alternatively, you can solve for x by equating the two path lengths, no need to differentiate.

The quadratic terms cancel. X=3d/2.

$$L=d\sqrt{7}$$